# Add Country code to URL along with Language code

Tags: sitecore-client, multilingual

The requirement is to have country code in the URL along with the Language code.

It's a Single site with multiple languages, it has one site definition, currently I am doing testing in local, and production is deployed in Azure PaaS environment. Sitecore version is 10.1.2.

Please suggest the best approach to have both country code and language code in URL.

I have set `languageEmbedding="always"` and Sitecore adds language code to URL, but our requirement is to include country code as well in the URL.

example : `sitename/zh-TW/TW/pagename`

In the above example "zh-TW" is language code and "TW" is country code.

**Updated:**

I have added country code to URL by overrding the "ItemUrlBuilder"

```
 public class ResolveURL : ItemUrlBuilder
    {
        public ResolveURL(DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions defaultOptions) : base(defaultOptions)
        {
        }
        public override string Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            if (Context.Site == null || Context.Site.Name == "shell" || !Context.Language.ToString().Contains("-"))
            {
                return base.Build(item, options);
            }
            options.LanguageEmbedding = Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Always;
            var countryCode = Context.Language.ToString().Split('-')[1];
            var newLangCode = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", Context.Language, countryCode);

            var itemUrl = base.Build(item, options).Replace(Context.Language.ToString().ToLower(), newLangCode.ToLower());

            return itemUrl;
        }

    }
```

It is adding country code to URL Sitename/zh-tw/tw/pagename

And Then i have override the "HttpRequestProcessor" to resolve the URL with country code "tw"

```
public class LanguageResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            if (Context.Site.Name == "mySitename" && Context.Language.ToString().Contains("-"))
            {
                Context.Item = Context.Database.GetItem(args.Url.ItemPath, Context.Language);

                if (args != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Url.ItemPath) && Context.Item == null)
                {
                    var countryCode = Context.Language.ToString().Split('-')[1].ToLower();
                    var countrycode = string.Concat("/", countryCode);
                    var ItemPath = args.Url.ItemPath.Replace(countrycode, "");

                    Context.Item = Context.Database.GetItem(ItemPath, Context.Language);
                   
                }

            }
        }
```

Even though am getting the correct Itempath, `Context.Database.GetItem(ItemPath, Context.Language);` gives me 404 error page and gives Item is null.

The strange thing is that for `sitename/zh-tw/tw/` it returns the home page correctly, but for other pages the Item is null.

Please advise what can be missing.

Comment: You need to include more details in your question - what is the structure of your website, where are those countries which you want to include in the url defined, etc

Comment: Its a Single site with multiple languages, have one site definition, currently am doing testing in local, production is deployed in azure PaaS environment. and its Sitecore 10.1.2

Comment: If there is one site only, there is really no country there. How should the content be different in different countries? Where is it specified?

Comment: We have single site with multiple languages, the requirement is to have country code ex: zh is the language code and tw is country code so the URL should have 'zh-tw/tw' in the url. by default sitecore resolves with "zh-tw" in the url, but requirement is to have country code as well